# "background-size:cover" not working in mobile landscape view

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, mobile-browser

In mobile landscape view, `background-size:cover` does not seem to be working. It does not cover the entire height of the browser. In portrait view, however, it seems to work fine.

I have this code in the CSS:

```
background-size:cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover; 
-moz-background-size: cover; 
-o-background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you don't really need vendor-prefixes for background-size (you might keep -webkit if you care about Android 2.3x; but prefixing was never used by any other vendor for this: http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size). Also, whenever using vendor-prefixed styles, the unprefixed version should come last so the final, built-to-spec implementation is used when it's available in a given browser

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```